# Is there a way of setting a property only once as a built-in mechanism?

Tags: c#, templates, properties, get, set

I've seen Marc Gravell's answer from May 8 '09 at 13:29
:

> ```
> public sealed class WriteOnce<T>
> {
>     private T value;
>     private bool hasValue;
>     public override string ToString()
>     {
>         return hasValue ? Convert.ToString(value) : "";
>     }
>     public T Value
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             if (!hasValue) throw new InvalidOperationException("Value not set");
>             return value;
>         }
>         set
>         {
>             if (hasValue) throw new InvalidOperationException("Value already set");
>             this.value = value;
>             this.hasValue = true;
>         }
>     }
>     public T ValueOrDefault { get { return value; } }
>
>     public static implicit operator T(WriteOnce<T> value) { return value.Value; }
> }
> Then use, for example:
>
> readonly WriteOnce<string> name = new WriteOnce<string>();
> public WriteOnce<string> Name { get { return name; } }
> ```

But i could not understand why would one create `readonly WriteOnce<T>` if its value is `private` anyway and it's using a property `Value` that can only be set once.
Also i couldn't get why would one create a property `Name` that only enables the get but not the set so:

1.You can't set name's value beacuse it's readonly and

2.You can't set it's value through the property cuz it's only get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing quite a few things here.

1. A readonly field means it can only be *assigned* inside a constructor or via a field initializer. Now `WriteOnce` is a reference type, so *assigning* only means that the value stored in `name` is a reference to the newly created `WriteOnce<string>` object.

   Nothing stops you from doing whenever you want `name.Value = "Hello";` because you are not changing the value of `name`. `name = whatever` outside a constructor or a field initializer on the other hand is disallowed becuase you are changing the value of the variable to a new reference, but nothing else.
2. `Name` is a readonly property, which has as the backing field `name`.

   A read only propery doesn't let you do `Name = new WriteOnce<string>()`, but `Name.Value = "Hello"` is perfectly fine.

   Anyhow, nowdays, you'd simply use a readonly autoproperty and let the compiler generate all the plumbing code (backing field):

   ```
   public WriteOnce<string> Name { get }
   ```

Comment: `public WriteOnce Name { get }` will not give you possibility to create an instance in "readable" way `var instance = new WriteOnce { Name = "test"};`

Comment: @Fabio this code is not even using autoproperties  I'm pretty sure this is pretty darn old and the intention of the code was that `name` was set via a constructor argument.

Comment: Thank you very much, your'e explnation with @Tom explnation made it really clear for me

Answer (score 1):

`readonly` means that the object can only be created or changed in the constructor. Making it only private and not `readonly` would allow any method to create new `name` field instead. So it's true that you could set the `Value` only once, but if object is not read only you could completely replace it with the new one.

Creatint `readonly WriteOnce` means that you can set the `name` value anytime, not just in the constructor, but once you set the value you can't change it and you can't replace it with the new `WriteOnce` object.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-write the class as a struct to make it a little simpler and easy to read.

```
struct WriteOnce<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }

    public WriteOnce(T input)
    {
        Value = input;
    }

    public static implicit operator WriteOnce<T>(T input)
    {
        return new WriteOnce<T>(input);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
WriteOnce<string> name = "test";
```

You can only change the value on instantiation so you will always know what it will be.

Comment: Care to explain down-vote so I could clarify better? It answers his title.

Comment: Making `WriteOnce` a struct would not let you do the following: `SomeClass.Name.Value = "Hello";`. You will get a compile time error because that code would not do what you expect it to do (which is basically nothing useful): `Can not modify the return value of  SomeClass.Name because it is not a variable.` That is one of the reasons why mutable structs are something to avoid, simply advising to use one is worth the down vote already.

Comment: Yes... you're not supposed to be able to. That's the entire purpose of the code. Why would you need to be able to do that? And this struct is immutable... what?...

Comment: This has nothing to do with `WriteOnce`, its about the fact the `SomeClass.Name` will give you a *copy* of the object because that is how value types work. You would be modifying the property of a copy that would be inmediately thrown away and the object you thought you were modifying would remain unchanged. This would be an unfortunate *gotcha* of the language and therefore the compiler dissallows it. If `Name` is a reference type, then you get the copy of the *reference* and everything is fine, because a copy of a reference will still point to the same object.

Comment: With immutable value types the issue is avoided altogether because you can't *change* the object so you would never fall into this trap to begin with. Makes sense now?

Comment: This struct is immutable. I have literally no idea what you're talking about. Just try it, I guess is the only thing I could say.

Comment: Lol! that happens because I read too fast..I assumed you were simply advising to change the original code form `class` to `struct`. 1000 apologies, just edit the answer and I'll remove the downvote ASAP. Really sorry, I need to go to sleep.

Comment: Ah, no problem, I was just really confused and thought I was missing something haha. No worries.

Comment: @Dispersia what is the preferation of struct over class in this case?
Also i don't want to call the constructor in order to set value but to just set it once via setter.

Comment: With it being a struct you can directly assign it to whatever your type T is. Just makes it a little more user friendly instead of typing `WriteOnce<string> name = WriteOnce<string>("test");` and why do you not want to use the constructor?